# how to refresh tab bar when click slide menu category

Tags: android

I have an Action Bar with Fragment as follow. I would like to refresh current fragment using slide menu  . i would like to change tab bar when click slide menu item. May I know how to get the current fragment and refresh the content.
[image]
after that i am select any category  of slide menu 
[image]

[image]

after that selecting category my fragment is refresh but my tab bar is still there so how to refresh my tab bar

Thanking You